# What is the difference between a light node and a full node GUI wallet?

Tags: iri-node, wallet, light-node

What is the exact difference between a full node wallet and a light node GUI wallet and which of both should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Full node

A full node **stores the whole Tangle**, it needs **neighbours** to broadcast transactions to and you need a **static IP** address or any other static address so that your neighbours can broadcast transactions to you.

## Light node

As a light node you do **not store the Tangle** and you **don't need any neigbours**.
You just need to select a **host** (e.g. `https://node.tangle.works:443`) which is a **full node** itself. This host provides your wallet with all the necessary information to make transaction.

## What do I need?

Full nodes need to  be online 24/7 and are only meant to run on servers.
If you just want a wallet for your laptop/PC that you turn on when you use it and off when you no longer use it then light node is the right choice for you

Answer (score 7):

I'll quote [learn.iota.org](https://learn.iota.org/faq/what-is-the-difference-between-the-lightwallet-and-full-wallet) here, because they have a good explanation.

> The IOTA GUI makes it possible to choose between Full Wallet, and
>   Light Wallet. The Full Wallet automatically runs an IRI (IOTA
>   Reference Implementation) instance in the background, which in turn
>   means that you need neighbors in order to participate in the network
>   and be synchronized. If you run the full wallet, you have no "trust
>   requirements", as you are completely and independently participating
>   in the network.
>
> The Light Wallet makes it possible to connect to a remote node
>   (whether it is your own node, or someone else's), and it's uses to get
>   the latest state of the network, most importantly branch/trunk
>   transactions which are required for making a transaction. When running
>   a Light Wallet, it should be noted that your seed never leaves your
>   wallet, and all the sensitive work (such as signing) is done
>   client-side.

As a normal user you should use the light node.